# MySQL Update with condition on the results from WHERE (SOLVED)

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, where-clause

How to update based on one/multi conditions from the results of `WHERE`?
For example?

```sql
UPDATE tb_a, tb_b, tb_c
SET tb_a.A = 
CASE 
  WHEN COUNT(tb_b.is_field_null IS NULL) = 0 
  THEN "OK" 
  ELSE "Nope" 
END
WHERE tb_a.a = "some" AND tb_a.b = "thing" AND tb_c.c = "else"
AND tb_a.b = tb_b.a
AND tb_c.b = tb_b.c
```

Given the tables are

tb_a

```
a          |    b        |      A
------------------------------------------
"some"     | "thing"     | "XXX"
"some"     | "thing"     | "YYY"
```

tb_b

```
a             | c           | is_field_null 
----------------------------------------------
"thing"       | "else"      | "I have things here" 
"thing"       | "else"      | NULL
"otherThing   | "otherElse" | NULL
```

tb_c

```
b            | c           | mapper 
----------------------------------------------
"else"       | "else"      | "ZZZ" 
"else"       | "else"      | "KKK"
```

I have tried without `COUNT` condition which resulted in the whole column `tb_a.A` modified to "Nope". Which is like

tb_a

```
a          |    b        |      A
------------------------------------------
"some"     | "thing"     | "Nope"
"some"     | "thing"     | "Nope"
```

But with the `COUNT`, there is an error of `Invalid use of group function`.
I have tried `if`,e.g.

`SET tb_a.A = (if COUNT(tb_b.is_field_null IS NULL) = 0, "Yes", "Nope")`,

condition but still error.

I would expect no modification at all.
Can someone help?

#### With answer from @forpas

I found that there is a problem. If tb_b is modified to

```
a             | c           | is_field_null 
----------------------------------------------
"thing"       | "else"      | "I have things here" 
"thing"       | "else"      | "I have things here" 
"otherThing   | "otherElse" | NULL
```

Then tb_a after the query is still

```
a          |    b        |      A
------------------------------------------
"some"     | "thing"     | "Nope"
"some"     | "thing"     | "Nope"
```

Is it the line `CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(is_field_null IS NULL) counter FROM tb_b) t` or `WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tb_b WHERE is_field_null IS NULL)` does not do the check with the returned results from the `WHERE` and `ON` clauses? It performs the check from the raw tb_b itself?

#### The 3rd query from `forpas` is working.

There is something I dont quite understand in such situation. From `forpas`'s first 2 queries, if I change them from `UPDATE` to `SELECT`, they select the first 2 rows in `tb_b` correctly. But in the `UPDATE` mode, neither

`CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(is_field_null IS NULL) counter FROM tb_b) t`

or

`WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tb_b WHERE is_field_null IS NULL)`

executed with the conditions from `WHERE` and `ON`. Does anyone can clear me up?

#### UPDATE

To the best of my limited knowledge, the current compact form to the question here is

```sql
UPDATE tb_a.A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(is_field_null IS NULL) counter 
   FROM tb_a
    INNER JOIN tb_b ON tb_a.b = tb_b.a
    INNER JOIN tb_c ON tb_c.b = tb_b.c
    WHERE tb_a.a = "some" AND tb_a.b = "thing" AND tb_c.c = "else"
) t
SET tb_a.A = CASE
  WHEN t.counter = 0 THEN "Yes"
  ELSE "Nope"
END
WHERE tb_a.a = "some"
```

Please refer to @forpas's answer for the full form solution as well as the brilliant alternative on `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: You must use something near `UPDATE tb_a, (SELECT tb_a.*, CASE ... END as new_value FROM tb_a, tb_b, tb_c, WHERE ...) as subq SET tb_a.A = subq.new_value where tb_a.* = subq.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper joins and also `CROSS JOIN` a query that returns the result of `COUNT(tb_b.is_field_null IS NULL)` like this:

```
UPDATE tb_a
INNER JOIN tb_b ON tb_a.b = tb_b.a
INNER JOIN tb_c ON tb_c.b = tb_b.c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(is_field_null IS NULL) counter FROM tb_b) t
SET tb_a.A = CASE 
  WHEN t.counter = 0 THEN "OK" 
  ELSE "Nope" 
END
WHERE tb_a.a = "some" AND tb_a.b = "thing" AND tb_c.c = "else"
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE tb_a
INNER JOIN tb_b ON tb_a.b = tb_b.a
INNER JOIN tb_c ON tb_c.b = tb_b.c
SET tb_a.A = CASE 
  WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tb_b WHERE is_field_null IS NULL) THEN "OK" 
  ELSE "Nope" 
END
WHERE tb_a.a = "some" AND tb_a.b = "thing" AND tb_c.c = "else"
```

Edit:

```
UPDATE tb_a
INNER JOIN tb_b ON tb_a.b = tb_b.a
INNER JOIN tb_c ON tb_c.b = tb_b.c
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT SUM(is_field_null IS NULL) counter 
  FROM tb_a
  INNER JOIN tb_b ON tb_a.b = tb_b.a
  INNER JOIN tb_c ON tb_c.b = tb_b.c
  WHERE tb_a.a = "some" AND tb_a.b = "thing" AND tb_c.c = "else"
) t 
SET tb_a.A = CASE 
  WHEN t.counter = 0 THEN "OK" 
  ELSE "Nope" 
END
WHERE tb_a.a = "some" AND tb_a.b = "thing" AND tb_c.c = "else"
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: I am sorry it does not work as expect if table b has some other entries witl is_field_null. I will update the question.

Comment: Do you also need the condition inside the subquery like: `CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(is_field_null IS NULL) counter FROM tb_b WHERE a="thing") t`?

Comment: This is what I guess, the `CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(is_field_null IS NULL) counter FROM tb_b WHERE a="thing") t` is performed directly on the tb_b which counted the irrelavant row, E.g. `"otherThing   | "otherElse" | NULL`. I would expect it counts on the row related by the where clauses and the `ON` clauses. E.g. There should be only 2 rows being evaluated.

Comment: It is weired, If I modify the statement to SELECT, it returns only the first 2 rows in tb_b as expected. However, the UPDATE one just provide the wrong result. Actually, no matter using `IS NULL` of `IS NOT NULL`, the same result is given.

Comment: See my 3d query.

Comment: Yes, the 3rd one is working. But does it means the subquery and main query performed something identical twice? It is really weired from my understanding why your original one does not work.

Comment: Yes the subquery does what the outer does also. I can't tell if the performance is good. It seems like you want to apply your condition only to the joined rows and not the whole tb_b.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right, the outer one is not neccessary since only elements in `tb_a` needs update. I am now cleared.